# Hosted Continuous Integration service for Mercurial repos on Bitbucket

Tags: saas, continuous-integration, mercurial

I have an open-source Java project in a mercurial repository, hosted on Bitbucket. 
I am looking for a basic hosted continuous integration service that can build my project and run unit tests whenever I push to the Bitbucket repo. Since the project is a tiny open-source tool, I am looking for a free solution.

So, to summarise:

- Automatic builds and JUnit tests whenever I push to Bitbucket
- Free for public open-source projects
- Integrates with Bitbucket
- Supports mercurial repositories
- Supports ant build scripts (optional)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with [Codeship](https://codeship.com/), which meets all my requirements.

Integration with Bitbucket was very easy - a few clicks and everything was set up. Their free plan is currently limited to 1 concurrent build and 100 builds per month, but this is plenty for my projects.

The only somewhat painful part was setting up the actual build script, although I haven't used any other hosted CI services, so it might be equally painful everywhere with the technologies I'm using.